# Excel - Inserting a cell value into a code string (surrounded by apostrophies)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create an excel sheet which will insert a value from a cell, into a string of code.

Here is the code:

```
sources: [{
                file: 'VALUE IN CELL A1',
        },{
                file: 'VALUE IN CELL A2',
                label: '360p',
        },{
                file: 'VALUE IN CELL A3',
                label: '180p',

        }],
```

Basically, the value in the cell will be a URL, and for it to be recognized by my video player, it needs to be surrounded by the apostrophe (')

However... the apostrophe seems to be stopping me from pulling up the "=cell(a1)" function and getting anything put in there.

*Edit* it was suggested that I use CHAR(39) for the apostrophe, but this doesn't seem to be working, and the cell value that I'm trying to reference doesn't even want to insert itself into a blank cell... let alone into the code.  Here's a video of what I'm experiencing;

https://www.dropbox.com/s/d253ildhnbn7o0k/stackoverflow.mp4?dl=0

Is there a way to do accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Your help would be very much appreciated!  Thank you for your time in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CHAR(39)` instead and it will display the single quote.

Comment: Hey, this still isn't working for me... having an additional error too.  Made this video to clarify:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/d253ildhnbn7o0k/stackoverflow.mp4?dl=0
(Thank you for your help so far)